# Different words for “giving away” with the same meaning in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I have to spin "giving away" text line but the best I could think "givin you" which does not work because of the number after it… Know of any other words that could replace "giving away" and sentence would still make sense?

Sentence example: As part of our new store opening we are giving away 120 limited discount codes.

Answer (score 1):

Some synonyms for *giving away* are:

> 1. Gifting
> 2. Rewarding/Awarding

From my retail experience, *gifting* is a more favourable word choice as it plays into a friendlier and customer serving relationship whereas *give away* sounds a tad belittling towards the customer and seems to carry a more negative connotation.

*Rewarding* and *awarding* are very similar in that they would be best used when the customer has to do something to get the discount code like show up to the store first or spin a wheel for a prize. If these codes are being just handed out randomly, I wouldn't use reward or award, as [reward](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reward) does mean to recognize and praise one for their actions.